# How to assign the logged-in user to the adminProfile field without using userService in the CompanyController?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I want to assign the logged-in user to the adminProfile field. Is it possible to do this without using userService in the CompanyController? I'm using JPA Repository

CompanyController

```
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CompanyController {

    private static final String COMPANY_PATH = "/companies";
    private static final String COMPANY_PATH_ID = COMPANY_PATH + "/{companyId}";

    private final CompanyService companyService;

    @GetMapping(COMPANY_PATH + "/create")
    public String creationForm(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("company", new CompanyDTO());

        return "company_create";
    }

    @PostMapping(COMPANY_PATH + "/create")
    public String createCompany(@ModelAttribute("company") CompanyDTO companyDTO) {

    }
```

CompanyDTO

```
@Builder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CompanyDTO {
    private Long id;
    private String companyName;
    private AppUser adminProfile;
}
```

I know that with userService here I can easily assign the user to adminProfile field, but I've read that using multiple services in a controller is considered bad practice